# Showing Custom Column Values from a Child Site in Searches on the Hub Site

Tags: search, hub-site, result-types

first time asker...I have a hub site and am designing search verticals (SharePoint Online Modern, no access to PnP).  For results (pages, folders, and list items) obtained on the parent (hub) site, I can list the values in a custom column called "TagList".  This is a mapped, crawled property that is a simple multi-line text field.  My problem is that I cannot get the same field to show for results that come from a child site.  I have set up my search vertical result format section that I want to show this as follows:

```
{
    "type": "TextBlock",
    "text": "Report Tags: ${TagList}",
    "spacing": "small",
    "color": "dark"
}
```

TagList is also a crawled, mapped property on the child site that is set to retrievable.  I have verified that there is data in the column, among other "idiot" checks.  Is what I am trying to do possible?  Can you give an overview of what I need to do if different from what I have done already?
Your expertise and help is much appreciated...just let me know if you require more info and I'd be happy to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure that the managed property ‘TagList’ is set to retrievable, searchable, and queryable in both the parent (hub) site and the child site.
2. The managed property should be correctly mapped to the crawled property. If ‘TagList’ is a site column, the crawled property is usually prefixed with ‘ows_’ (e.g., ‘ows_TagList’).
3. After creating or modifying a managed property, perform a full crawl to ensure that the changes are reflected in the search index.
4. In the display template, map the managed property in the ‘ManagedPropertyMapping’ tag. You can fetch the column in the search results like this: `_#=ctx.CurrentItem.TagList=#_`

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: 1-3 have been done ad-nauseum...trying #4.

Comment: Hi Martin.  Quick question:  it looks like your response implies I have to do this with a custom template (_#=ctx.CurrentItem.TagList=#_ does not seem to be a standard JSON payload reference like ${....}).  Am I able to reference the column and retrieve the content in the JSON payload definition for a result type associated with a search vertical?  I can offer more code if that would help....

Comment: Hi yes you can reference the column and retrieve the content in the JSON payload definition for a result type associated with a search vertical. In SharePoint Online, you can use column formatting to customize how fields in SharePoint lists and libraries are displayed, construct a JSON object that describes the elements that are displayed when a field is included in a list view, and the styles to be applied to those elements. 

referenced here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting